# JavaScript traversing through arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying javascript after 15 years, so not a pro at this. I finished the grouping & sorting on array. Need help with traversing & setting the values in the result.

PART 1 -
input data array -

```
var arr = [
      { id: 1, name: 'fryh', name1: 'ksdtfuy', group: '1208', DT: '2019-10-02T19:20' },
      { id: 2, name: 'fthy', name1: 'xdhftdx', group: '1209',  DT: '2019-10-02T09:27' },
      { id: 3, name: 'qjkgjwer', name1: 'dhfdt', group: '1208',  DT: '2019-10-02T09:24' },
       { id: 4, name: 'jlkke', name1: 'atth', group: '1208', DT: '2019-10-02T19:20' },
      { id: 5, name: 'gfhjm', name1: 'dryt', group: '1208',  DT: '2019-10-02T09:28' },
      { id: 6, name: 'iuit', name1: 'xx', group: '1209',  DT: '2019-10-02T09:24' },
    ];
```

want to group this based on group then sort it based on DT. Achieved this using the below code & the result is in grouped.

```
function ReSeq(){
        var grouped = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
            if(!grouped[arr[i].group]) {
            grouped[arr[i].group] = [];
          }
          grouped[arr[i].group].push(arr[i]);
        }
        for (var group in grouped) {
          grouped[group] = grouped[group].sort(sortByPosition);
        }       
        console.log(grouped);               
    }
var sortByPosition = function(a, b) {
  var dateA = new Date(a.position), dateB = new Date(b.position);
  return dateA - dateB;
};
```

Below is what is printed on console - Question is how do I traverse grouped & set values. Example i want to set values of name1 colum in grouped. basically i want to give it sequence so 1st entry in name 1 would be 1 the 2nd one would be 2 ...So the Need is to traverse the output object & set values in name1

```
{1208: Array(4), 1209: Array(2)}
1208: Array(4)
0: {id: 3, name: "qwer", name1: "xx", group: "1208", position: "2019-10-02T09:24"}
1: {id: 5, name: "qwe", name1: "xx", group: "1208", position: "2019-10-02T09:28"}
2: {id: 1, name: "qw", name1: "xx", group: "1208", position: "2019-10-02T19:20"}
3: {id: 4, name: "qw", name1: "xx", group: "1208", position: "2019-10-02T19:20"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
1209: Array(2)
0: {id: 6, name: "qwer", name1: "xx", group: "1209", position: "2019-10-02T09:24"}
1: {id: 2, name: "qwe", name1: "xx", group: "1209", position: "2019-10-02T09:27"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Provide expected output?

Comment: If i correct understood what you need is that just put in each group name an sort number? For example : `{id: 6, name: "qwer", name1: "1-xx", group: "1209", position: "2019-10-02T09:24"}
1: {id: 2, name: "qwe", name1: "2-xx", group: "1209", position: "2019-10-02T09:27"}`

Comment: yes. Something similar to that .. i dont need xx but either ways , need a way to modify name1 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are several ways to do that. Here, `Array.forEach` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) is used to revalue .name1 and `for (let x in [obj])` to iterate through the object entries:

```js
// use Array.reduce to group
const sortedAscendingAndGrouped = getArr()
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(a.DT) - new Date(b.DT))
  .reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc,
    [val.group]: (acc[val.group] || []).concat(val)
  }), {});

// traverse sortedAscendingAndGrouped groups
// and number the .name1 values, using 
// Array.forEach
for (let entry in sortedAscendingAndGrouped) {
  sortedAscendingAndGrouped[entry]
    .forEach( (row, i) => row.name1 = (i+1) + "-" + row.name1);
}

console.log(sortedAscendingAndGrouped);

function getArr() {
  return [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'fryh',
    name1: 'ksdtfuy',
    group: '1208',
    DT: '2019-10-02T19:20'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'fthy',
    name1: 'xdhftdx',
    group: '1209',
    DT: '2019-10-02T09:27'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'qjkgjwer',
    name1: 'dhfdt',
    group: '1208',
    DT: '2019-10-02T09:24'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'jlkke',
    name1: 'atth',
    group: '1208',
    DT: '2019-10-02T19:20'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'gfhjm',
    name1: 'dryt',
    group: '1208',
    DT: '2019-10-02T09:28'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'iuit',
    name1: 'xx',
    group: '1209',
    DT: '2019-10-02T09:24'
  },
];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```